# Hard disk keeps making noise even if not used

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems

Since yesterday my secondary hard disk keeps making noise as if it were reading/writing even if it's unused. It happens regardless of the OS running (both windows7 and linux) and I'm sure it's not used since under linux no partition of that disk is mounted on the filesystem.

I can say for sure it's the secondary one as the main disk is an SSD.

What could be causing this?

Comment: There are a number of things that could cause it. We don't know your system, so we can't tell you that. The first thing to do is make a backup then run diagnostics on it. Have you done that?

Comment: It sounds like the drive is about to fail.  You should retrieve and backup all data and replace the drive.

Comment: Has the drive S.M.A.R.T. capabilities and are the enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be a failure of some kind that hasn't affected the data yet.   It could also be the drive recalibrating which most disks do from time to time, and they do try to do this during idle periods so as to not affect performance.  This recalibration shouldn't last too long though.

If it's a failure that hasn't affected data it could run for years like this or it could fail tomorrow (but then again, so could any hard drive). Running diagnostics, while worth doing, might not turn up anything [yet].  Diagnostics are not a good indicator of pre-data-failure conditions unfortunately (this is why RAID and backups are standard IT practices).  By the time you have a reportable error the disk likely has already started losing or corrupting data.

Try leaving it running (on) and idle for a day to give it plenty of time to recalibrate and finish its business.  If after that this sound persists I would replace the drive as soon as possible (don't forget to check if it's under warranty).  If it's making noises it shouldn't that's not good or normal.

Definitely have backups at the ready regardless.

Comment: I have left the PC idle for quite some time but the noise didn't stop, it was a constant buzz every couple of seconds or so with no reason at all for any kind of activity. As it seems that the only reason is a hardware failure, I just replaced the disk with a spare one.